# How to evaluate a string to a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I do this?

```
var myVar = "$(this).parents('section').first()";
myVar.hide();
```

I tried using eval() but it doesn't work

```
var myVar = "$(this).parents('section').first()";
var obj = eval(myVar);
obj.hide();
```

Can anyone please help. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine the problem is because `this` refers to something different inside the `eval` context. Is there a reason *why* you need to do this? There are a limited number of good uses for `eval`.

Comment: eval is not the correct function to use at all here. I'm just wondering if there is a way to turn a string like this into a jQuery object.

Comment: Why does it need to be in a string? You could just do `var myVar = $(this).parents('section').first()` and then `myVar.hide()`

Comment: I'm reading it from a data tag that the designer might supply in the HTML. It will have to come in as a string because it's a variable that my class needs to work on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(this).parents('section').first()).hide()
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation instead of just posting single lines of code.